# Filtering view using where condition

Tags: mysql, sql, view

I have a view named as new_view. I want to filter the contents of my view using the where conditions. I have written below query. its returning zero rows.

```
SELECT * FROM analyticsdata.new_view
where  client_name='Client 1';
```

If i use below code, i am able to filter january month values.

```
SELECT * FROM analyticsdata.new_view
where  month1='January';
```

Out put of the above code
 [image]

What may be the problem with my first query.

Comment: You have no rows with either that client name or campaign name.  If you think you do, try setting up a SQL Fiddle so we can see the problem, along with the original data.

Comment: try `OR` instead of `AND`  coz your view may not have `client_name='Client 1' and campaign_name='Campaign 1'`

Comment: Plz check the updated question. I attached snapshot of the data

Comment: This is just a speculation, as I do not see anything wrong with your first query. Try enclosing the column name in backticks, like so : \`client_name`.

Comment: @CodeNewbie : still not getting the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If

```
SELECT * FROM analyticsdata.new_view
where  client_name='Client 1';
```

doesn't find any data, then there is none. Maybe it's 'Client 1 ' or ' Client 1'?

Try

```
SELECT * FROM analyticsdata.new_view
where  trim(client_name) = 'Client 1';
```

Maybe this solves the issue.

Comment: Too bad. It should be something like that. Any control character or a tab instead of space. Anything like that, so client_name doesn't equal 'Client 1'. Have a look into the selected data. Or maybe you can try with LIKE, e.g. `where client_name like 'Client%'` or `where client_name like '%1'` till you are there.